# Bug: QGIS freezes editing large polygon, does not save window or toolbar positions after crashes

Tags: qgis, editing, vertices

Version: 3.14.15

Activity causing freezing: attempting to delete more than 20 vertices of a 61,000+, complexly-shaped polygon - hangs when deleting as few as 4 vertices

Annoyance: layer and browser windows and default taskbar positions always reset to defaults; in addition, most recent project disappears from main starting window

Comment: thats a big polygon. try making sure it is the only layer in your project. Turn off any snapping (Project > Snapping Options) .

Comment: Could be more of an hardware / memory error than a QGIS one depending on your computer spec...

Comment: but what's the question?

Comment: Please use https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/new/choose to report bugs.